# Multi-level grouping and aggregation in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model that look like this:

```
class Price(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    date = models.Dateield(auto_now_add=True)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

There are no unique constrains on multiple columns each book can have multiple prices for a day for the same publisher.

I would like to group all the prices but first I'd like to group all the prices (average) for a particular publisher for a particular day. This would effectively return a unique record on date, publisher and book.

Then I'd like to group all the prices (sum) for a particular book for a particular day.

Here's the SQL I would write:

```
SELECT book_id
     , DATE(date) as date
     , SUM(price) AS price
  FROM
     ( SELECT book_id
            , DATE(date) as date
            , AVG(price) AS price
            , publisher_id
         FROM literature_prices
        GROUP
           BY date
            , book_id
            , publisher_id
     )
 GROUP
    BY book_id
     , date
```

This was easy to in SQL but I'm not sure how I would do the same using the Djano ORM. Any help?

Comment: Did my answer help solve your aggregation problem? Please up vote and select as an answer if correct.

Comment: Nopes. That hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation api in Django is well documented here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

An example of aggregating by publisher in your example would be.

```
 query_set = Price.objects.extra(select={'count': 'count(1)'}, 
                           order_by=['-count']).values('count', 'publisher')

 query_set.query.group_by = ['publisher']
```

For multi-level. I believe you can keep calling aggregate() and group_by functions on the query_set object.

Comment: Be careful with relying on `QuerySet.query.group_by`. Its use is undocumented and from what I've read, the results are pretty mixed, occasionally working great for some and other times blowing up for others. The current Django-endorsed method of GROUP_BY is the `values(...).annotate(...)` approach. (discussion at link Matt provided). It's not ideal, but it'll work reliably. I agree this is something that Django should have dealt with long ago, but for the moment, I'm not sure recommending a hack is necessarily the right approach.

Comment: Hi Matt, I'm having a little trouble figuring this out. I wrote: `Price.objects.filter(price__isnull=False).extra(select={'date': 'DATE(date)'}).values('id', 'book_id', 'publisher_id', 'date', 'price')` and it worked fine. Since I'm on SQLite, I need to convert those timestamps to a valid date. When I to aggregate this by adding a `.aggregate(Avg('price'))` I get an empty dict. I'm pretty lost why this happening.

Comment: Are you price values non null? Are they numerics? An alternative is to step over the Django model and write SQL on the SQLlite db. (the group by syntax will work as normal here)

Comment: There aren't any non numeric values in the table, I just checked. It is a nullable field though and that's why the filtering clause. I'm trying to do this using the Django ORM but it looks like I'll have to use raw SQL. The whole ORM seems very flimsy and is almost useless the moment you hit something remotely complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use your SQL query as a view and create a Django model around that view.

Detail explanations can be found here: http://anthony-tresontani.github.com/Django/2012/09/12/wka-django-orm-limitations/